# Countdown Countup F# Recursion

Tags: recursion, f#, pattern-matching

I need help to create a recursive function that will count down to 0 and then count back up to 3 in F#.

```
 let rec  countdownThenCountUp number goingup =
 match number with




  | number -> 0  goingup; true
  | number -> >0 goingup; false
  | number -> 3  goingup; done
```

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: I can't get it to print out the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You would not learn much if people just provided a working solution, so I'll instead just add a couple of hints.

Your basic strategy of defining a recursive function `countdownThenCountUp` is good. However, your function only takes `number` as an argument, which is not enough. For example, when you call:

```
countdownThenCountUp 2
```

How does the function know whether it should be counting up or down? It does not have enough information for that! So, you'll need to modify the function so that it has an extra parameter. You could do something like:

```
let rec countdownThenCountUp number goingDown = 
  // (...)
```

If you do this, then the logic in the function needs to be roughly:

- If `number` is more than zero and `goingDown` is `true`, then count down
- If `number` is zero then call recursively with `goingDown` set to `false`
- If `number` is three and `goingDown` is `false` then stop

You can implement the conditions using pattern matching or using `if` - both will work fine.

Comment: | number -> 0  goingup; true
      | number -> >0 goingup; false
      | number -> 3  goingup; done  like this?

Comment: Try to write full function definition that compiles first and then you can either edit the question or add a new one with more clear problem statement.